# How To Make three picturebox that move Simultaneous?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 3 pictureboxes (boardTop, boardCenter, boardBottom). When the up arrow or down arrow keys are pressed, I want these three pictureboxes to move together.

```
private void PingPong_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
    {
        boardUp.Location = new Point(boardUp.Location.X, boardUp.Location.Y - 1);
        boardLeft.Location = new Point(boardUp.Location.X, boardUp.Location.Y - 1);
        boardDown.Location = new Point(boardUp.Location.X, boardUp.Location.Y - 1);
        Kup = true;
    }
    else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
    {
        boardUp.Location = new Point(boardUp.Location.X, boardUp.Location.Y + 1);
        boardLeft.Location = new Point(boardUp.Location.X, boardUp.Location.Y + 1);
        boardDown.Location = new Point(boardUp.Location.X, boardUp.Location.Y + 1);
        Kdown = true;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You are moving boardUp correctly. But for other boards, you are using boardUp location.

Comment: i tried your code and it's work perfectly as you descried... so unable to understand you want to say

Comment: Works for me too, just fixed the locations (he's using boardUp locations only) and I dont have Kdown and Kup bools. There's a timer so I guess, he's trying to do somehting with it what messes things up

Comment: @PranavPatel  as also Vegs So you didn't pay attention the OP is moving boardLeft and boradDown using the location of boardUp: **boardLeft**.Location = new Point(**boardUp**.Location.X, **boardUp**.Location.Y - 1);

Comment: ohh yes... i just tyr to do myself and didn't see that part
thx @RezaAghaei

Comment: @RezaAghaei,Sorry, I didn't notice.

Comment: No problem, it's just a mistake. If you don't need them separately, you can put them in a panel or user control and move the panel or user control.